# Get value of tapped UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

So I am currently creating dynamic labels, and I need to get their value when tapped. I am creating labels number 1 through 10 with a for loop. I then add them to the view along with `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detect when tapped. What I need to do is get the text of the tapped label. So if I clicked the label with the text of `1`, I'd expect to have the `1` returned. Here's what I'm doing to create the label and adding the gesture recognizer.

```
   for number in numbers.characters {
       let touch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: "numberClicked")
       touch.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

       let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(x), CGFloat(y1), CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height)))
       label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(38)
       label.text = String(number)
       label.userInteractionEnabled = true
       label.addGestureRecognizer(touch)
       self.view.addSubview(label)
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is considered opinion-based. It asks a basic "how to" question with respect to a particular API. Answers aren't based mainly on opinion, but rather on how the `UILabel` class actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of getting the text of the label in your action function. The key change is to add a colon to the name of the tap action, indicating it takes a sender argument. Then you can access the `view` property of the sender to get at the `UILabel` itself.

```
for number in numbers.characters {
    // add a colon after "numberClicked" to indicate it takes an argument
    let touch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: "numberClicked:")
    touch.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(x), CGFloat(y1), CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height)))
    label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(38)
    label.text = String(number)
    label.userInteractionEnabled = true
    label.addGestureRecognizer(touch)
    self.view.addSubview(label)
 }


func numberClicked(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .Ended {
        if let theLabel = (gesture.view as? UILabel)?.text {
            print(theLabel) // print the "1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `func numberClicked(sender: UILabel) { if let theTitle = sender.text { ... } }`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It appears that `theView = sender as? UILabel` isn't true :(

Comment: @LeoDabus when attempting to do it your way, I get an error saying that `text` is unavailable as it is deprecated

Comment: @LeoDabus Added the explicitly typed version. Thanks.

Comment: The app crashes when attempting to set the argument as `UILabel.` However when using `AnyObject`,   `theLabel = sender as? UILabel` isn't true

Comment: looks like the sender it is a UIView

Comment: Would that be caused because of `addSubview`? @LeoDabus

Comment: maybe the issue is there UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, where self is the view

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, I think so. Thought this was a `UIControl` for a moment. I edited my answer.